# creating blogroll by inoreader, feedly or similar ones

Tags: google-reader, feedly

In Google reader(R.I.P) we could select some interesting links by a special tag and then make public them and show links on our blogs or websites.

Is there a way to create this by Google reader alternatives like [Inoreader](http://www.inoreader.com/) or [Feedly](http://www.feedly.com/) or [AOL reader](http://reader.aol.com/) or etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I should probably start by saying that I'm the [BDFL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benevolent_dictator_for_life) of Inoreader, but I feel obliged to answer you. If anyone thinks my answer is inappropriate or that this can be achieved with one of the other mentioned options, feel free to bash me in the comments :)*

Yes, you can do that in [Inoreader](http://www.inoreader.com).

Since you are familiar with Google Reader, you shouldn't have much difficulties starting up with it, but if you have, [here's a quick guide](http://blog.inoreader.com/2015/02/inoreader-how-to-setting-up.html) to get you started.

Depending on what you need to achieve the option you want is accessible via right-click on a folder or a tag:

[image: Right-click on a folder or a tag to get the context menu]

Then in the dialog that pops up, you will see an `Export` option. Click it and you will get 3 links - for RSS feed, HTML page (what you need) and a public OPML file (for folders only):

[image: The folder/tag information dialog containing links for RSS and HTML snippets]

A few notes on folders and tags:

Folders are used to group sources (RSS, social and other feeds) and content inside them is automatically populated from the feeds.

Tags on the other hand are *mostly* manually populated by you. When you read an article and you find it interesting, you can press "T" or click the label icon at the bottom of article to tag it. This behavior is almost identical in all major RSS readers. Working with tags in Inoreader is covered in detail in [this blog post](http://blog.inoreader.com/2015/04/inoreader-how-to-be-more-productive.html).

Now I said *mostly* before, because tags can also be automatically populated by Inoreader's Rules. Basically they works like your email filter. You can set up keywords or other conditions and tag articles automatically as they arrive. This feature is covered in [this blog post](http://blog.inoreader.com/2015/03/inoreader-how-to-save-time-with-rules.html).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I see that you are from Iran. Inoreader is also fully localized into Persian with proper RTL support. You might want to change your language in Preferences -> Interface.